# pandas dataframe with identical column names - is it valid process?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I was able to produce a pandas dataframe with identical column names.
Is it this normal fro a pandas dataframe? 
How can I choose one of the two columns only? 
Using the identical name, it has, as a result, to produce as output both columns of the dataframe?

Example given below:

```
# Producing a new empty pd dataset
dataset=pd.DataFrame()

# fill in a list with values to be added to the dataset later
cases=[1]*10

# Adding the list of values in the dataset, and naming the variable / column
dataset["id"]=cases

# making a list of columns as it is displayed below: 
data_columns = ["id", "id"]

# Then, we call the pd dataframe using the defined column names:
dataset_new=dataset[data_columns]

# dataset_new
# It has as a result two columns with identical names.
# How can I process only one of the two dataset columns?

   id  id
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   1
5   1   1
6   1   1
7   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.iloc` to access either column.

```
dataset_new.iloc[:,0]
```

or

```
dataset_new.iloc[:,1]
```

and of course you can rename your columns just like you did when you set them both to 'id' using:

```
dataset_new.column = ['id_1', 'id_2']
```

Comment: But i guess i cannot access them individually by its name only?

Comment: No, That name is a label, both columns are identically labelled.   You can accces the via there index value.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
lst = ['1', '2', '3']
df[0] = lst
df[1] = lst
df.rename(columns={0:'id'}, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={1:'id'}, inplace=True)
print(df[[1]])
```